# ¿Generar una n cantidad de filas en un datagriedview segun un numero ingresado en un textbox?' en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb

he creado un formulario donde tengo un textbox, un boton y un datagriedview, lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente: ingresar un numero en el textbox y al dar clic en el boton me genere una cantidad de filas en el datagriedview segun el numero que e ingresado, por ejemplo si ingreso el numero 5 tendria que generarme 5 filas en el datagriedview, lo estoy intentando con un bucle for pero no genera la cantidad que le ingreso. desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

If isnumeric(textbox1.text) then

For k as integer=1 to cint(textbox1.text)

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(k.tostring())

Next

En if